# Custom Timer Job for SharePoint 2007 using Visual Studio installed in separate system

Tags: 2007, custom-timer-job

I need to create one custom job for SharePoint 2007. But the harden is that is on another server while i need to develop that on my system using visual studio 2010.  I have dll of SharePoint 2007 to use.

Now, I know couple of thing...

1) I need to take Class Library Project and Add Reference of that SP2007 Dll....

2) I Need to inherit one class from SPJobDefinition and override Execute Method

3) I need to inherit one class from SPFeatureReceiver and override FeatureActivated

4) I need to create one feature.xml

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Id="b9e40341-32ab-410a-a20f-282cf13fb54b" ReceiverAssembly="SharePointSocialNetworking, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=6264b0911592ad29" ReceiverClass="SharePointSocialNetworking.FeatureToEnableJob" Scope="Site" Title="SharePoint Social Networking Job">
```

1) Should i need to create this feature.xml  or mycustom.webpart ?

2) What would we the steps to install this in that server ? I mean can anyone step down here ? where i should copy dll and use which command to deploy & enable & update

3) Should i need to register that in GAC ? How would i will get PublicToken of this project dll ? In this Xml Scope="Site" Correct or will be Web or Farm ?

4) Don't know what is the difference between this feature installation and webpart installation ? what is applicable here ?

5) After Install how would I update my Dll when changed ?

Really Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't use .webpart files for timer jobs

2) You don't copy any DLLs anywhere, you would use WSPs to deploy your solution

3) WSP deployment will register the DLL in the GAC. VS2010 has tokens to get the PublicKeyToken. Scope of the Feature depends on where you want the Timer Job to be created. It's usually Web Application

4) This isn't a web part, it's a timer job ;)

5) You need to properly implement a proper Application Lifecycle Management system where you version control your solution source and control the upgrades of the WSP.

6) Bonus: Looks like you might need a primer in SharePoint Development. I would highly consider looking into a bootcamp development course local to you.